# retrieve of email and password from MySql databse using springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

*I want retrieve user email from MySql database table using spring boot.i used findByEmailAndPassword in controller but it retrieve null value for email.
Here is my Code*

> controller

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    import com.example.demo.JPARepository;
    import com.example.demo.pojo.regisbean;

    @Controller
    public class registerController {
        regisbean pp;
        @RequestMapping(value =  "/")
        public String mm() {
            System.out.println("I am in m1 method");
            return "index";
        }
        @RequestMapping(value = { "/register", "home" })
        public String m1() {
            System.out.println("I am in mm method");
            return "register";
        }
        @Autowired
        JPARepository jpaRepository;
        @PostMapping("/register")
        public String regis(@ModelAttribute regisbean rb)
        {
            System.out.println("I m in regis method");
            regisbean b=jpaRepository.save(rb);
            if(b!=null)
                return "index";
            else
                return "fail";

        }
        @RequestMapping(value= {"/login1","login2"})
        public String m2() {
            System.out.println("i m in m2()");
            return "login";
        }
        @PostMapping("/login")
        public String login(@ModelAttribute regisbean rx,Model m) {
            System.out.println("I am in Login");

            regisbean re=jpaRepository.findByEmailAndPassword(rx.getEmail(), rx.getPassword());
            if(re!=null)
            {
                m.addAttribute("email",rx.getEmail());
                m.addAttribute("password",rx.getPassword());
                System.out.println("yes");
                return "loginsuccess";
            }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(rx.getEmail());
                    System.out.println("failed");
                    return "register";
                }


        }


    }
```

> pojo class

```
 package com.example.demo.pojo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "pro")

public class regisbean {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String email;
    @Column
    private String phonenumber;
    @Column
    private String password;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    public String getPhonenumber() {
        return phonenumber;
    }

    public void setPhonenumber(String phonenumber) {
        this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

> Repository

package com.example.demo;

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.example.demo.pojo.regisbean;

public interface JPARepository extends CrudRepository<regisbean, Integer> {
    public regisbean findByEmailAndPassword(String email,String password);

}
```

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character

Comment: Do not store passwords as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your code to work by inserting a row in the table:

```
INSERT INTO pro (
    id
    ,email
    ,name
    ,password
    ,phonenumber
    )
VALUES (
    0
    ,'user@domain.com'
    ,'Jim'
    ,'secret'
    ,'123-123-1234'
    )
```

Then changing:

```
public String login(@ModelAttribute regisbean rx,Model m) {
```

to:

```
public String login(@RequestBody RegisBean rx,Model m) {
```

and POSTing the following request body to the /login resource:

```
{
    "email": "user@domain.com",
    "password": "secret"
}
```

I didn't have to make any changes to your Repo. I suspect your attempt was failing because RegisBean was never being initialized with any values and so the repo was asked to find a record with a null email and a null password.